# Swim into the water

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Is it correct to say "I swim into the water" as a synonym of "I dive"?

Thank you

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site [ell.se]

Comment: [Swim](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swim?q=swim) vs [dive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dive).

Comment: No, it is not correct. One *enters* the water. This could be by diving, or lowering oneself, or walking into the surf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're a turtle, I wouldn't recommend "swimming into the water".
As for your exact question, no, it's not the same.
Diving means jumping in head(arms) first.
Swimming into the water is something only turtles do, if it's not already classified as crawling.

Comment: Ok just so you know, when you, as a human, swim into the water, imagine laying on your belly on land, making swimming motions pushing yourself into the water like some sort of weird animal.

Comment: It sounds fun, but I don't think I'll try it. Thanks a lot for your  answer and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

'Dive' is totally distinct from "swim into the water". The former refers to a forceful action of entering into the water, presumably after a jump; while the latter refers to an action with less force. What are you trying to imply anyway? What is the context? Will be glad to help

Comment: I understand by your answer that both expressions are correct and mean going underwater, but "diving" is more like jumping into the water and "swimming into the water" is less forceful. Is that right?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No, both are not correct.

Dive into the water means to enter the water head first, usually after being airborne ("flying" through the air).

Jump into the water means to enter the water feet first after being airborne ("flying" through the air).

Swim into the water is not correct.  Into means going from not being in the water to being in the water.  This is not something that can be done by swimming.

So, in your example, only "Dive into the water" would be correct if the person entered the water head first.

Comment: "Jump into the water means to enter the water feet first after being airborne ("flying" through the air)." Incorrect. Jumping into the water is a generalisation of all the ways to jump into the water. You can jump into the water with a triple salto and a 360 for all I care. It's still jumping into the water. Also, his question is whether Diving and swimming into the water are synonimical to eachother. Which they aren't. He hasn't said anything stating that he's going to jump in head first.